# How is 'contact modified' defined as on CiviCRM reports?

Tags: custom-reports

I'm looking to run a report that only shows contacts who we've engaged with (registered for an event, joined our database, updated their details) in the past 12 months. Would the 'contact modified field deliver this report? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! The Contact modified date filter will work to filter contact that are modified in past 12 months

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this for GDPR purposes?  If so, you might find the [GDPR extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr) useful.  Among other things, it lets you specify which activities you want to include/exclude when determining whether there has been contact with individuals.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at the console, although this isn't strickly-speaking for those purposes . Thank you!